# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator JOOQ 3.8

Tags: jooq

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
```

On this command

```
java -cp "jooq-3.8.5.jar;jooq-meta-3.8.5.jar;jooq-codegen-3.8.5.jar;ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar" org.jooq.util.GenerationTool library.xml
```

Is there something more that I need besides these jars? I was looking at the jooq 3.8 documentation and it didn't seem to list anything else.

I'm using jooq 3.8 because in later versions you need to buy a license for Oracle.

Comment: *"I'm using jooq 3.8 because in later versions you need to buy a license for Oracle."* - You need a license for using jOOQ with Oracle in jOOQ 3.8 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ 3.11 renamed code generator packages because of the problems the previously split packages are now causing in JDK 9+: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7419

If you want to downgrade your jOOQ distribution to a version prior to jOOQ 3.11, please use the relevant documentation pages on the jOOQ manual, e.g. https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/, to configure your code generator.

In your particular case, the class was called `org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator` before jOOQ 3.11.

However, if you want to use the jOOQ Open Source Edition with Oracle, you will have to downgrade to jOOQ 3.1 (which is more than 6 years old now), so I definitely don't recommend this downgrade.

Comment: Oh woof, I guess I would need to go back farther than I'd thought. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Steve: I really recommend reconsidering commercial licensing. We've been *very* busy improving jOOQ over the past 6 years! https://www.jooq.org/notes

Comment: I'm sure that jooq is fantastic, but I work in a corporate environment and getting any kind of expenditure requires massive hurdles for me to jump over. It'd be far easier to just go with something else that's open source.

Comment: @Steve: How can we make that easier for you?

Comment: @PAA this question already contains your answer. The class was renamed

Comment: @LukasEder - Could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444988/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-jooq-util-jaxb-tools-xmlappenda? I am not sure what wrong is here?

Comment: @PAA: I've already answered your question (you're using the wrong class name because the class was renamed), and your question was also answered correctly by Siva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451450/521799. Now all that's left for you to do is to actually read that answer :)

Comment: @LukasEder - I uploaded my source code: https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-boot-jooq-integration. I am still facing the same issue, not sure what is going wrong in my way !

Comment: @PAA: Well, I'm glad I quickly checked the other question again prior to looking at your upload ;-)